# HTACCESS Issues Resulting in 401 and Multiple 302

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have a website that is on a PHP MVC based framework.

I've added password protection to the entire site until I'm ready to make it accessible to the public.

I'm trying to implement site wide HTTPS. I've already had the EV SSL cert installed on the server (Apache).

When I added the code to the htaccess to force all urls to redirect to https, I receive a "401 error due to multiple 302 redirects".

The exact error I receive when visiting my website is:
This webpage has a redirect loop. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I've already researched this topic heavily with no solution. Any help and explanation of my mistake would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the exact code in my htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css  text/javascript
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# start https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [R,L]
# end https

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# header modifiers
# By default allow all access
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

# Password protect entire site until launch
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "restricted area"  
AuthUserFile /home/mydirectory/public_html/.htpasswd  
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

The above code always works for me.
Can you access secured(https) pages directly on the browser?

Make sure you have configured your apache correctly for HTTPS.

Sample configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your_domain_name.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your_private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: No, I cannot access secured pages directly on the browser. Also, after adding your code -- the error still occurs AND it redirects me to the HTTP version instead of the HTTPS version. Weird.

Comment: you can't access https://www.example.org directly in the browser? There's a hint. I actually pasted in your .htaccess file and it works for me, so if you can't access https by typing it in the browser, then you're redirects are not going to work either. you might want to take a look at your main httpd.conf/apache.conf or other *.conf files to see if there's something else redirecting that port.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII - is it possible there is some internal code related to my MVC is causing this error? It's a custom MVC framework that I did not create, but I'm assuming based on what I'm seeing that there has to be something internal going on here, aside from the htaccess.

Comment: yes, that's a great point. good luck combing through that if you didn't write it. but I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with your .htaccess file. you might try doing a search for "header(" to see if anything is setting the location to hard coded http:   http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Thanks for your time and help, @JeffPuckettII. Luckily, albeit I didn't create it, I'm familiar enough with it to know where to at least start my search. I'll update this thread with the solution once found -- in the event it can help anyone else using a similar setup. Thanks again!

Comment: maybe you can also check all the redirects going on using this tool
http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php